# Modal issue when Integrating multiple react native application in existing swift application

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, modalviewcontroller

I have multiple react native application which I need to load in existing IOS application.

So I have a bottom tab bar in ios which are Home, profile, news, activities.

On news and profile I load the react native bundle through a single bridge.

When I click on news tab in my UIViewController the news bundle gets rendered. In news bundle I have a button on click of which Modal gets opened.

Now when I click on profile and again  goes to news tab and click on the button, my modal is getting on profile screen instead of news screen.

I have done some RCA on it, once the tab gets loaded ios does not rerender the content of the tab again, so what I am thinking is the reference of UIViewController is not getting updated inside the react native due to which it is loading the view on incorrect screen.
It would be great if anyone can help me in this